# Not receiving the value after submitting the form in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple form that takes value from ajax and submit it through form. Now i am not able to get the value after form submission.

Here is my HTML form

```
<form name="frm1" action="process_view_detail.php?cand_id=<?php echo $_SESSION["id"] 
?>" method="post">
<?php
$q=$_GET["x"];
include('connection.php');
$sql ="select * from  register where name like '%$q%' &&`r_bid`='".$_SESSION["id"]."'
";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>   
<select name="rid" style="height: 30px;padding: 6px;width: 280px;">                                                   
<option value="">  Select Details  </option>
<?php
while( $data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo'<option value='.$data["r_id"].'">'.$data["name"].'('.$data["reference"].
'</option>';            
}                                           
echo'</select>
<input type="button" value="Find Details" on Click=\'f1()\'>
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript code that checks whether the user have chosen a value or not.

```
function f1()
{
ok=0;
a=document.frm1.elements.rid.value;
b=a.length;
if(b=='')
{
alert("Please select Details to view info.");
ok=1;
}
if(ok==0)
{
document.frm1.submit();
}
}
```

Here is my process_view_detail.php

```
<?php                       
$cand_id=$_GET['cand_id'];
$id=$_POST['r_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from register where `r_id`='$id' & r_bid='$cand_id'");
$res=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($res!=0)
{
$count=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo'<h2 class="title"><font size=5 color=#8B4513><u><center>Client Info</center>
</u</font></h2>';
echo '<table border=0 align="center" width=40% >                                
<tr><td><table width=100%>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>Name</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>Reference</td
<td>'.$row['reference'].'</td</tr>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>Email</td><td>'.$row['email'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>Mobile No.</td><td>'.$row['mob_no'].'</td
</tr>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>Address</td><td>'.$row['addr'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>DOB</td><td>'.$row['dob'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>Age</td><td>'.$row['age'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>Blood Group</td><td>'.$row['blood_grp'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><font size=5 font color=brown><i>Occupation</td><td>'.$row['occupation'].'</td>
</tr>
</font></table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';
$count++;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: does it take you to some action or remain in same page

Comment: show us the `process_view_detail.php`

Comment: Here is process_view_detail.php

Answer (score 1):

If the action is on a different page try using `$someval = $_POST['rid'];` to receive your form data.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$id=$_POST['r_id'];
```

it should be

```
$id=$_POST['rid'];
```

Comment: but i am sending $row['r_id'], it is my database field

Comment: <select name="rid" style="height: 30px;padding: 6px;width: 280px;">.

see this in your html file. Name of your select box is 'rid'